# Unresolved identifier for currLocation and other corelocation functions

Tags: swift, parse-platform, core-location

I'm working on an app that's trying to get the users location and viewing the content in a query. I've added corelocation in the framework and imported it onto the viewcontroller but I get an error saying "currLocation" is an unresolved identifier and "location manager" is ambiguous under the queryfortable function and location manager function. How can I fix this error?

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Parse


@available(iOS 8.0, *)

class TableViewController: UITableViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let bubbleFeeds = [
        ("1"),
        ("2"),
        ("I3"),
        ("4"),
        ("5"),
        ("6") ]


    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D?


    private func alert(message : String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops something went wrong.", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
        let settings = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
            return
        }
        alert.addAction(settings)
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    var resultsNameArray = [String]()
    var resultsImageFiles = [PFFile]()
    var resultsBubbleArray = [String]()



    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return resultsNameArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BubbleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Bubbles
        let BubbleCell = PFObject(className: "BubbleTest")

        cell.name.text = PFUser.valueForKey("userName") as! String
        cell.message.text = PFObject.valueForKey("textField") as! String
        cell.dateTime.text = "\((indexPath.row + 1) * 3)m ago"
        cell.message.numberOfLines = 0
        let score = PFObject.valueForKey("count") as! Int
        cell.LikeCounter.text = "\(score)"
        let replycnt = PFObject.valueForKey("replies") as! Int
        cell.responseCounter.text = "\(replycnt) replies"
        cell.img.image = PFUser.currentUser()?.valueForKey("photo") as! PFFile

        return cell


    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = 1000
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        _ = currLocation

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        ("Cannot fetch your location")
    }
}
```

It's in these sections of the code where I'm running into errors with "currLocation" and the "locationManager" being ambiguous.

```
func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "BubbleTest")
    if let queryLoc = currLocation {
        query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: PFGeoPoint(latitude: queryLoc.latitude, longitude: queryLoc.longitude), withinMiles: 10)
        query.limit = 200;
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    } else {
        /* Decide on how the application should react if there is no location available */
        query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: PFGeoPoint(latitude: 37.411822, longitude: -121.941125), withinMiles: 10)
        query.limit = 200;
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    }

    return query
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    if(locations.count > 0){
        let location = locations[0]
        print(location.coordinate)
        currLocation = location.coordinate
    } else {
        alert("Cannot receive your location")
    }
}
```

I've been trying to solve this for the last 2 days and it's driving me nuts. If someone could please help I'd much appreciate.

Comment: If you have `queryForTable`, why not use Parse's `PFQueryTableViewController` instead of a plain `UITableViewController`? Also, check out Parse's convenience method `geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:`. Lastly, this link should answer your question: https://parse.com/questions/pfgeopoint-current-location-with-pfquerytableview

Comment: I fixed the issue doing something else but now I'm getting this error when I build and run the app: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<PFUser 0x10b32baa0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key userName". What can I do to fix this?